# System.InvalidOperationException: Object is currently in use elsewhere. in coding a snake game

Tags: c#, forms, exception, object, graphics

So i was coding a snake game in the past and something went wrong. All that i know is that during I try to play, when the snake is in a certain place on the screen it throws an exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Object is currently in use elsewhere.
    at System.Drawing.Image.get_Height()
    at System.Drawing.Image.get_Size()
    at System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox.ImageRectangleFromSizeMode(PictureBoxSizeMode mode)
    at System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox.OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
    at System.Windows.Forms.Control.PaintWithErrorHandling(PaintEventArgs e, Int16 layer, Boolean disposeEventArgs)
    at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmPaint(Message& m)
    at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
    at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
    at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
    at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

and when I'm debugging it marks the following piece of code:

```
for (int i = 1; i < myS.organs.Count; i++)
    if (squares[myS.organs[i].Y, myS.organs[i].X].Image == null)
    {
        **squares[myS.organs[i].Y, myS.organs[i].X].Image = b;**//this is the line it marks.
    }
```

I know it's not enough information but it's all I got. I really can't figure out where this problem is coming from, so if you need more information guide me so I can give you... thanks!

Comment: Is your code multithreaded?

Comment: Where is the value of 'b' coming from?  Is it a static or dynamic value, and when is it being set?

Comment: it is not multithreaded, but it uses timer.

Comment: and 'b' is coming from the form itself (this is a field of the form)

Comment: If the code is not multi-threaded and you are getting this error, it may have to do with the timer.  Are any of these values (myS) being set or used before or during the timer duration?  That operation may not be finished when it gets to this line.

Comment: that might be it. But how can I fix it without making the interval length longer?

Comment: I don't think the interval length is necessarily the issue.  I think there is a logic error somewhere in your code that is causing the block. Trying debugging and refactoring, one option you can look into is locks.

Comment: but then again, it happens only in a certain place on the screen, so I don't know if thats it.